# erb comment vi plugin

Tags: plugins, comments, vi, erb

I always use nerdcommenter to comment blocks in my code, and it works pretty well on almost all kinds of programming languages. However, I have been editing a lot of .html.erb files recently. When I comment

```
<%= text_field_tag 'sid',nil,:class=>"input-medium search-query" %>
```

after typing `,cb`

I got the following result

```
<%#<%= text_field_tag 'sid',nil,:class=>"input-medium search-query" %>%>
```

what I want is

```
<%#= text_field_tag 'sid',nil,:class=>"input-medium search-query" %>
```

How do I make it work or are there any other good plugins for editing erb files under the vi editor.